# How do I fix ConstraintLayout that include Balloon(gives strange results) in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout, popup-balloons

I'm trying to make a help pop ups in my first app. the problem that came up after making the pop up work is that the icon which I'm using becomes a button taking up whole screen height.
I'm using the only code I found for [balloon popups](https://github.com/skydoves/Orchestra) in jetpack compose.
the layout is fine until I add the BalloonAnchor.
this is the code:

```
@Composable
fun GiveHelp(helpText: String) {
Surface{
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    ConstraintLayout {
        val (icon, text) = createRefs()
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(icon) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                },
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_help),
            contentDescription = "help Icon"
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(text) {
                    top.linkTo(icon.top)
                    start.linkTo(icon.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(icon.bottom)
                }
                .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
            text = "Is your task:"
        )
        BalloonAnchor(
            reference = icon,
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(0.1f),
            balloon = BalloonUtils.getTitleBalloon(
                context = context,
                title = helpText,
                lifecycle = lifecycleOwner
            ),
            onAnchorClick = { balloon, anchor -> balloon.showAlignTop(anchor) }
        )
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you wanna use `ConstraintLayout` you have to add `Modifier.constrainAs` for each view - without it its size is inconsistent. But generally you almost always can build layout without it, in this case seems like `Row` should work. I suggest you start with [Layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts) to get basic principles

Comment: i did use the Modifier.constrainAs but it still does the same for some reason @PylypDukhov

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the **aspectRatio** you are using in the Modifier of **BalloonAnchor**. Try something like `Modifier.aspectRatio(0.99f)`. Using this, your Icon will not take the entire screen height. 
 **Or**, your can use something like below code to get a desirable look.

```
BalloonAnchor(
    reference = icon,
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(40.dp),
    balloon = BalloonUtils.getTitleBalloon(
        context = context,
        title = helpText,
        lifecycle = lifecycleOwner
    ),
    onAnchorClick = { balloon, anchor -> balloon.showAlignTop(anchor) }
)
```